# Why doesn't Angular add the ngcontent-c# attribute selector to my components styles

Tags: css, angular

As I can understand from inspecting, when having a global style, Angular usually creates a rule in the styles.scss without the ngcontent attribute (bottom rule) and one with the ngcontent attribute (top rule):

[image]

But for one of my components it didn't create a rule with the ngcontent attribute (only a rule without one):
[image]

So with component "sgn-c355", the attribute is missing (no shadow DOM was created maybe? Why?).

actually the _ngcontent-sgn-c355 attribute appears everywhere in the html, but does not at all in the css in the inspect tools. So to rephrase my question:
how is this possible, what are the possible causes for the styles not getting the ngcontent attribute?

Comment: No. Sry I forgot adding a red arrow to mark „the second example“ rule I am talking about. The rule that I‘m curious about is „button.mat-stroked-button“ (and that one certainly I wrote (: ). There is no rule „button.mat-stroked-button[ngcontent…]„ only one without that attribute-selector…

Comment: I came across the same weird issue. How did you resolve it?

Comment: not googling too much and just finding a workaround. Often with such messy code where sth like this causes a problem it's just better to not try to write clean code on top of spaghetti code but just find a quick solution